# Best way to approximate roots of a binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem, interpolation

If it makes any sense, what is the best way to find the root of a binomial expansion for any values of *n*, without using interpolation?

For example, how will you solve for a
$${(1+a)^{25}}=\frac{3000a-300}{2500a-300}$$

Probably, you can expand the left-hand side using binomial expansion, but it would be tedious. How would you go around about it?

Comment: Have you tried substitution? E.g. by setting $b = a + 1$.

Comment: It would breed the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant in the comment.

$${(1+a)^{25}}=\frac{3000a-300}{2500a-300}
=\frac{30a-3}{25a-3}$$
Set $b=a+1$
$$b^{25}=
\frac{30b - 33}{25b - 28}$$
$$b^{25}
\left(25b - 28\right)=30b - 33
$$
$$25b^{26} - 28 b^{25}
- 30b + 33 = 0
$$
Okay, it's not very nice, but at least the tedious binomial expansion was avoided. A numerical solver might be applied to estimate a root.

Comment: can you check my answer? or at least tell me if it is proper to use the approximant

Answer (score 0):

My best guess so far.

$$1+a=\frac{\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}n]{Y}\cdot\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}n]{a-b}}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}n]{Xa-Yb}}$$

Substituting $a=z^n$, gives the following:

$$1+z^n=\frac{\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}n]{Y}\cdot\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}n]{z^n-b}}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}n]{Xz^n-Yb}}$$

Newton's first approximant:

$$\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}n]{x+y}\approx x+ \frac{y}{nx^{n-1}}$$

If it is applicable, the equation (possibly, if I'm correct) returns:

$$1+z^n\approx \sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}n]{\frac{Y}{X}}\cdot\frac{n+z^n}{nz^n-b}$$

Comment: I confess that I'm no longer sure what you're asking. From the original question, I understood that aim was to find a way to avoid carrying out a long binomial expansion. The aim appears now to be different and I'm no longer sure what it is. Perhaps there is a second question here?